# Web.config Security Level

Tags: asp.net, windows, azure, web-config

I have a little question about the web.config file. Is it a secured file, I mean is this file can be accessed from the outside ?
I see a lot of system to secure it but it seems that it's only for developement security.
But what about "outside security" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's secure in that no one will be able to get into your Cloud Service (Web Role) unless they have access to your Windows Live ID (point of weakness) or obtain a .rdp file to it, they would still need to know your username and password to get in mind you. If you are worried why not follow the developer security and encrypt the fields in there.

IMO its more secure then someone breaking into your enterprise source control system and stealing them out of there.

The Windows Azure Trust Center goes into a lot more detail, safe to say it's one of the most secure Data Centers in the world: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/trust-center/security/

Comment: Nice blog on the Dev approach 'Encrypting and Decrypting application config sections': http://www.davidgiard.com/2012/06/05/EncryptingAndDecryptingApplicationConfigSections.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Actually, web.config file not protected by Azure or WebRole. It's protected by IIS itself. All files that match "*.config" wildcard mapped by default to HttpForbiddenHandler (except *.dll.config and *.exe.config, they have another registered handler)

You can find all default mappings in the global (parent to all yours w.configs) web.config file, which located here "c:\<Windows>\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<v4.0.30319>\Config\web.config"
you can see a lot of handlers registered by default for different file masks:

```
<configuration><system.web><httpHandlers>
    <add path="*.config" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" validate="True" />
```

You can redefine this behaviour in your own config, in case you need it, but it's strongly not recommended for "security sensitive" files.
So "protection" of web.config built-in into IIS itself.